# How to replace certain records in a table with another table using "merge"?

Tags: r

I want to replace "O" in table t1 with table t2 using "merge":

```
t1<-data.frame(x1=c(1,2,3,4,5),x2=c("a","O","O","b","a"))
t2<-data.frame(x1=c(2,3),x2=c("a","b"))
first <- merge(t1["x2"=="O",],t2,by="x1")
```

The result was supposed to be like this：

```
t1<-data.frame(x1=c(1,2,3,4,5),x2=c("a","a","b""b","a"))
```

But I didn't get it.

What's the problem?

Comment: That's not really a join; a simpler approach would just be to assign to the subset: `t1[t1$x2 == 'O',] <- t2`

Comment: `subset(merge(t1,t2,all=TRUE), x2 != "O")`

Comment: @alistaire@thelatemail Thank you! This is to the point!

Answer (score 2):

I guess `merge` is messy here (and I wouldn't mess around with this `"O"` encoding). You can do

```
m = match(t1$x1, t2$x1)
t1$x2[ !is.na(m) ] <- t2$x2[ m[!is.na(m)] ]
```

This doesn't extend to merging by more than one column, so I'd recommend data.table:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(t1)[t2, on="x1", x2 := i.x2]
```

Answer (score 0):

This can probably be cleaned up. This is using the `dplyr` package

```
first = left_join(t1, t2, by = "x1") %>%
  mutate(x2 = ifelse(x2.x == "O", as.character(x2.y), as.character(x2.x))) %>%
  select(x1, x2)
```

Comment: I just have problem with downloading "dplyr", perhaps bacause of win10 system.

Comment: @JadaChang A guess, but make sure the file that `.libPaths()` points to is writable; a lot of Windows people seem to have permissions issues with the default.

Comment: Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) :